# Aligning title, subtitle and caption for horizontal ggplot barchart

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to left align the `plot.title`, `plot.subtitle` and `plot.caption` in a horizontal ggplot2 barchart.

*Example:*

```
library("ggplot2") # ggplot2 2.2
df <- data.frame(type=factor(c("Brooklyn",
                               "Manhatten and\n Queens")),
                 value=c(15,30))

# manual hjust for title, subtitle & caption
myhjust <- -0.2

ggplot(df,
       aes(x=type, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(
    title = "This is a nice title",
    subtitle = "A subtitle",
    caption  = "We even have a caption. A very long one indeed.") +
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
        plot.title=element_text(hjust = myhjust),
        plot.subtitle=element_text(hjust = myhjust ),
        plot.caption=element_text(hjust = myhjust))
```

How can I align all 3 `labs` elements (`plot.title`, `plot.subtitle` and `plot.caption`) to where the `axis.text` starts (red vertical line, "M" of Manhatten)?

Besides: Why does a fixed  `myhjust` result in 3 different horizontal positions for `plot.title`, `plot.subtitle` and `plot.caption`?

[image: Problem]

Comment: This is a great question, well illustrated, and clearly explained.  It is a problem that I run into frequently with ggplot.  While the grid.arrange() alternative below is workable, to me it isn't a full answer to this question.  For instance, why doesn't the same hjust value affect title, subtitle, and caption the same?  I think the answer is that the reference point is the middle of the text string in each case. While this is sensible for center justified text, it does not work for left or right justification beyond the plot area.  It seems like this should be a simple setting.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This question refers to this github tidyverse/ggplot2 solved issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3252

And it is implemented in ggplot2 (development version): https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/15263f7580d6b5100989f7c1da5d2f5255e480f9/NEWS.md

> Themes have gained two new parameters, plot.title.position and plot.caption.position, that can be used to customize how plot title/subtitle and plot caption are positioned relative to the overall plot (@clauswilke, #3252).

To follow your example as a reprex:

```r
# First install the development version from GitHub:
#install.packages("devtools") #If required
#devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")

library(ggplot2)
packageVersion("ggplot2")
#> [1] '3.2.1.9000'

df <- data.frame(type=factor(c("Brooklyn","Manhatten and\n Queens")),
                 value=c(15,30))

ggplot(df, aes(x=type, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title = "This is a nice title",
       subtitle = "A subtitle",
       caption  = "We even have a caption. A very long one indeed.") +
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, face= "italic"), #Default is hjust=1
        plot.title.position = "plot", #NEW parameter. Apply for subtitle too.
        plot.caption.position =  "plot") #NEW parameter
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-09-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 12):

While you *could* edit those three grobs, you can also just:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

grid.arrange(
  textGrob("This is a nice title", 
           gp=gpar(fontsize=16, col="#2b2b2b"), 
           x=unit(0.005, "npc"), just=c("left", "bottom")),
  textGrob("A subtitle",  
           gp=gpar(fontsize=12, col="#2b2b2b"), 
           x=unit(0.005, "npc"), just=c("left", "bottom")),
  ggplot(df, aes(x=type, y=value)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity') +
    coord_flip() +
    theme(axis.title=element_blank()),
  textGrob("We even have a caption. A very long one indeed.", 
           gp=gpar(fontsize=9, col="#2b2b2b"), 
           x=unit(0.005, "npc"), just=c("left", "bottom")),
  ncol=1,
  heights=c(0.075, 0.025, 0.85, 0.05)
)
```

Make a wrapper for it, put it in a personal pkg. Boom. Done.

---

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

df <- data.frame(type=factor(c("Brooklyn","Manhatten and\n Queens")), value=c(15,30))

ggplot(df, aes(x=type, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.title=element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.margin=margin(l=0, t=5, b=5))-> gg

flush_plot <- function(x, title, subtitle, caption) {
  tg <- function(label, ...) {
    textGrob(label,  x=unit(0, "npc"), just=c("left", "bottom"),
             gp=do.call(gpar, as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L])) }
  grid.arrange(
    tg(title, fontsize=16, col="#2b2b2b"),
    tg(subtitle, fontsize=12, col="#2b2b2b"), x,
    tg(caption, fontsize=9, col="#2b2b2b"),
    ncol=1, heights=c(0.075, 0.025, 0.85, 0.05)
  )
}

flush_plot(gg, "This is a nice title", "A subtitle", 
           "We even have a caption. A very long one indeed.")
```

Comment: This aligns the title, subtitle and caption, but not the y-axis labels, it seems.

Comment: `plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0),"line")` would fix that

Comment: @hrbrmstr Great answer! But to be honest: I would prefer a pure ggplot2 solution though with less code...if there is one /-: