# Reproduce plot having data source

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Considering the following data, I am trying to write the code to reproduce a plot initially made with Excel.

```
df = data.frame(year = c(rep(2013, 4), rep(2014, 4), rep(2015, 3)),
                quarter = c(rep(c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"), 2), c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3")),
                Miss = c(5, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5.7, 12, 15, 20, 33, 42),
                Meet = c(100-40-5, 100-37-3, 100-29-7,100-28-4,
                         100-20-6, 100-29-5.7, 100-27-12, 100-25-15,
                         100-13-20, 100-5-33, 100-12-42),
                Exceed = c(40, 37, 29, 28, 20, 29, 27, 25, 13, 5, 12))

footnote = "Data source: XYZ Dashboard; the total number of projects has increased over time from 230 in early 2013 to nearly 270 in Q3 2015."

textbox = "As of Q3 2015, more than 1/3 of projects are missing goals"

title = "Goal attainment over time"

y_label = "% of total projects"
```

I am trying to write a generalizable code to obtain a result as much as possible similar to:
[image]

#### The main issues I am encountering is a "simple" approach to align the elements (title, axis label, legend, text box) in the plot.

Comment: This should be doable. What code have you written for a plot so far?

Comment: Let's consider @Calum You answer a good starting point. Tought `textbox` should not be added in `subtitle` because otherwise it is not possible to align it properly

Comment: @camille have you got any useful hint?

Comment: I would suggest something similar to what @calum you did below, but like they said it's helpful to know what you've tried so we're not starting from scratch

Comment: Mine is far worse than @Calum however his solution is still far from the expected result. I am start thinking that R is not made for this type of customized visualizations. Do you agree?

Comment: I think it's possible. The text boxes might require cobbling together some grobs, maybe with `cowplot`

Comment: But again, it's much easier to help if we can see what you tried, especially what you've tried to get the alignment how you want, since you say it's not as good as @Calum You's

Comment: But wouldn't this be a time-consuming approach, especially if you want to adopt it in your work routine?

Comment: Possibly, possibly not. Here's a previous discussion that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105759/aligning-title-subtitle-and-caption-for-horizontal-ggplot-barchart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you want to be generalisable and what can be flexible, but here's my first attempt. Missing custom colouring on the subtitle and a few other tweaks, improvements welcome.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <-  tibble(
  year = c(rep(2013, 4), rep(2014, 4), rep(2015, 3)),
  quarter = c(rep(c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"), 2), c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3")),
  Miss = c(5, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5.7, 12, 15, 20, 33, 42),
  Meet = c(100-40-5, 100-37-3, 100-29-7,100-28-4,
           100-20-6, 100-29-5.7, 100-27-12, 100-25-15,
           100-13-20, 100-5-33, 100-12-42),
  Exceed = c(40, 37, 29, 28, 20, 29, 27, 25, 13, 5, 12)
)
footnote = "Data source: XYZ Dashboard; the total number of projects has increased over time from 230 in early 2013 to nearly 270 in Q3 2015."
textbox = "As of Q3 2015, more than 1/3\nof projects are missing goals"
title = "Goal attainment over time"
y_label = "% of total projects"

tbl <- df %>%
  gather("category", "value", Miss:Exceed) %>%
  mutate(
    quarter = parse_factor(quarter, levels = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4")),
    category = parse_factor(category, levels = c("Exceed", "Meet", "Miss"))
  )

ggplot(tbl, aes(x = quarter, y = value)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_col(aes(fill = category)) +
  geom_text(
    data = . %>%
      mutate(
        text = str_c(value, "%"),
        text = case_when(
          category != "Miss"                        ~ "",
          year == 2013                              ~ "",
          year == 2014 & quarter %in% c("Q1", "Q2") ~ "",
          TRUE                                      ~ text
        )
      ),
    mapping = aes(label = text, y = value - 4),
    position = "stack",
    col = "white"
    ) +
  facet_wrap(~ year, strip.position = "bottom") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#777777", "#A3A3A1", "#7F141A")) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, 100, 10),
    labels = function(x) str_c(x, "%"),
    expand = c(0, 0)
    ) +
  labs(
    title = title,
    x = "",
    y = y_label,
    # subtitle = textbox,
    caption = footnote,
    fill = NULL
  ) +
  theme(
    text = element_text(colour = "#888888"),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "#E3E3E3"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = 1),
    legend.justification = "left",
    legend.position = "top",
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 1),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 7.5, colour = "#D0D0D0"),
    strip.placement = "outside"
  ) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE, keywidth = 0.6, keyheight = 0.6))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: This is more or less what I achieved. The issues still are the alignment of: title, legend and textbox.

Comment: It would have helped if you posted what you actually did already so we could figure out what to tweak.

Comment: @CalumYou in `geom_text()` what does the following line `data = . %>%` mean? I want to understand the significance of `dot` after `data=`

Comment: the `.` in the `data` argument of a geom refers back to the original `data` supplied to `ggplot()`. So here I want to create `label` based on `value` in `tbl`, so I modify the data to create this inside `geom_text`.