# Adding subtitle under the main title or adding a subtitle under y axis in R

Tags: r

I was wondering how I can add a subtitle under the main title and the y-axis.

Comment: For a "subtitle under the y-axis" perhaps you could use a left-aligned caption, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57792599/12957340

Comment: I am using the standard plot graphics in R

Answer (score 6):

### Update

Sounds like this is what you want:

```
plot(mtcars[3:4])
title(main = "My Plot")
mysubtitle = "Subtitle here"
anothersubtitle = "Another subtitle here"
mtext(side = 3, line = 0.25, at = 1, adj = -2, mysubtitle)
mtext(side = 2, line = 2, anothersubtitle)
```

[image: example_3.png]

Comment: Like right under My Plot or Right under hp.